# Animate cells inside a grid to change their position

Tags: jquery, css

I've been animating the grid as shown in the code below. I want the divs exchange their position between each other as clockwise.

I do not have any errors in my code except for behavior of the div movement, they go outside the grid.

```js
var distanceLeft;
var distanceTop;
var myVar;
var c1 = $(".left-top");
var c2 = $(".right-top");
var c3 = $(".right-bottom");
var c4 = $(".left-bottom");

function swapDiv(firstDiv, secondDiv) {
  distanceLeft = secondDiv.offset().left - firstDiv.offset().left;
  distanceTop = secondDiv.offset().top - firstDiv.offset().top;
  firstDiv.animate({
    left: distanceLeft,
    top: distanceTop
  }, 2000)
};

function roll() {
  swapDiv(c1, c2);
  swapDiv(c2, c3);
  swapDiv(c3, c4);
  swapDiv(c4, c1);
};
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left-top  right-top' 'left-bottom right-bottom';
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  ;
  /*grid-gap: 5px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: magenta;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-top {
  grid-area: left-top;
}

.right-top {
  grid-area: right-top;
}

.left-bottom {
  grid-area: left-bottom;
}

.right-bottom {
  grid-area: right-bottom;
}

.grid-container div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick=roll() id="swap">SWAP</button>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left-top" style="position: relative">1</div>
  <div class="right-top" style="position: relative">2</div>
  <div class="right-bottom" style="position: relative">3</div>
  <div class="left-bottom" style="position: relative">4</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ana-belkis-granados-arozarena/pen/vYBWwNM

Comment: yuor code works fine, but you forgot to re-assign the classes according to the new divs position. for example after the first swap your div.left-top should become div.right-top

Comment: You're right... It works ok in Code Pen but dosen't work in my aspx page.